# Difference between executing hive queries on mapreduce vs hive on spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

By default hive query runs on map reduce backed by YARN engine. We could use TEZ as and execution engine for performance when we work with hortonworks distribution.We could also run hive on SPARK which is also backed by YARN, then Could you please explain me in detail the PROs and CONs of using hive on spark execution with respect to performance , efficiency and other factors.

```
set hive.execution.engine=spark;
```

vs

```
set hive.execution.engine=mr;
```

Comment: This guide should help you: https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12652517/Hive-on-Spark.pdf

Comment: Some benchmarks put Tez performance ahead of Spark (for example running on ORC files)

Comment: This might be outdated, but shows that Hive on Tez is quite good option already: https://www.slideshare.net/HadoopSummit/llap-subsecond-analytical-queries-in-hive-63959757